# EOS connection to react native app

Tags: eosjs, mobile, react

Can someone share an example of EOS blockchain integration with react-native? I am new to EOS development and I am struggling to integrate it in react-native app, there are always some missing dependencies or libraries.. Any help, link, tutorial or just code would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The EvaCoop-Team forked *eosjs* to make it more compatible with react-native. Async handling in react-native is a big mess with the original eosjs.

Here's the link to the git [react-native-eos](https://github.com/EvaCoop/react-native-eos) which also contains examples.

Comment: Thank you @cmadh, I saw the react-native-eos git but I had some difficulties connecting my application to the blockchain and I switch to only eosjs. I am currently stuck with eosjs npm package issues, so I will try again with react-native-eos and I will keep you posted.

Comment: can you post some of the errors you have?

Comment: Hello @cmadh, currently I am getting: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'setUrl' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)`

Comment: Solved it and currently I am having `Error: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:8888` while using `ReactNativeEos.setUrl('http', '127.0.0.1', 8888);` and ReactNativeEos.pushAction. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I'm guessing that should point to a EOS node, put in the address of a block producer instead of localhost perhaps, like eos.greymass.com or nodes.get-scatter.com

Comment: But I am running local docker node on Ubuntu and trying to connect to it.. isn't that the node that I should connect to ?

Comment: Have you forwarded the port while running docker with `-p 8888:8888`?

Comment: Yes, the port is forwarded: 
`$ docker run \
  --name nodeos -d -p 8888:8888 \
  --network eosdev \
  -v /tmp/eosio/work:/work \
  -v /tmp/eosio/data:/mnt/dev/data \
  -v /tmp/eosio/config:/mnt/dev/config \
  eosio/eos-dev \
/bin/bash -c \ `

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to **read data** you can use the [EOS RPC API](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference).
Then you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (for [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network)) to connect to it promised based.

Your code could look something like this to read from a table of a contract.

```
fetch(<http://{host}:{port}/v1/chain/get_table_rows>, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    code: <name of the smart contract>,
    table: <The name of the table to query>
}),
}).then(
 (result) => {
   // do something with result.json()
   // which will look like this
   // {
   // "rows": [
   //   {
   //     "account": "account",
   //     "balance": 1000
   //   }
   // ],
   // "more": false
   //}
 }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @TeeAtack42 I already opened issue here: https://github.com/EvaCoop/react-native-eos/issues/4 because I am using react-native-eos, but it seems that I am not going to get anything in response. However, my idea is to have local node and be able to transfer coins from one to another account that is registered on the network using react-native.

Comment: Ok. I have looked into your GitHub issue. Have you tried varying the url? I think `localhost/127.0.0.1:8888` seems to be referring to your local machine twice. Maybe try to remove the `localhost` and place an empty string.

Comment: A little bit late.. I tried it but it didn't helped so I switched to REACTJS only and everything works fine by now. Thanks for helping guys.